# Can't catch moment of Lync shutdown

Tags: lync

I' m developing an application that catch all the conversations and do stuff, so I use

```
_lyncClient.ConversationManager.ConversationAdded += ConversationManagerConversationAdded;
```

However I want my application doing stuff even when Lync is restarted. So I use a Timer to check whether Lync is running.

```
public static bool LyncPresented
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            _lyncClient = LyncClient.GetClient();
            return true;
        }
        catch(ClientNotFoundException)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Can't found a working Lync instance.");
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

For the first time I start my app without running Lync I can see that Lync not started. Then I run Lync and now I can found it. And then I shudown Lync but `LyncClient.GetClient()` not throwing exception anymore and my app still considering that Lync is available.

What am I doing wrong? What is the right way to determine whether Lync is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why, but the following code is working

```
public static bool LyncPresented
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            _lyncClient = LyncClient.GetClient();
            bool dummy = _lyncClient.InSuppressedMode;
            return true;
        }
        catch(ClientNotFoundException)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Can't found a working Lync instance.");
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the ClientDisconnected event instead of your loop.